# how i get 2 dimentional array responseby split s string

Tags: android

How to split `String` and get 2 dimentional `Array` result.
I want my answer in [ ][ ]Array.
How do I split single `String` message and get result in [ ][ ]Array

```
public static String[][] SMSAgAppXMLParser( String parUrl) 
{
    String [][] xmlRespone=null;
    String[] parts;
    parts = parUrl.split("\n");
    xmlRespone = new String[ parts.length/2 ][2];

    for (int j=0,  i = 0;  i < parts.length-1+2; ) {
        xmlRespone[j][0] =  parts[i];
        xmlRespone[j][1] = parts[i+1];
        j++;

    }
return xmlRespone;      
}
```

Comment: What is the Error you are getting in executing the above code ?

Comment: is not go in this line   when debug

return xmlRespone;

Comment: If you had the problem in splitting the 1-D array into 2-D array,then please see my Answer.I will solve your problem.